# CSS aliased image during the time of the transition in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I trigger an image to show, when a button is clicked.

It comes from outside of the screen and slides in from the left.

In Chrome (only), during the period of the animation, the image is aliased, and gets to normal when it reaches the final position.

Here's my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Heart_2_").click(function() {
    $(".resize-logo").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.resize-logo {
  width: 30px;
  /* you can use % */
  height: auto;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  -webkit-animation: anim 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-150%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar transparent navbar-static-top">

  <div class="navbar-header">
    <img src="" class="resize-logo" style="display: none" />
  </div>

</nav>

<button id="Heart_2_">PUSH</button>
```

How can I get rid of the alias when the image is moving ?

Comment: Do you see this issue in all browsers or just some? It's possible that it is simply a rendering bug and there's no "fix". However, there might be a hack.

Comment: Only in Chrome, I should have mentioned that. I'm editing my post.

Comment: Can you convert your code into a running snippet?

Comment: I've only experienced what you're describing when using the `transform` property. When animating via `margin` or one of `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left`, I've not seen it happen.